# how to convert from decimal to ASCII characters

Tags: java

Im trying to write a function that will convert the last two Hex in a string to ASCII characters.  like "ab3A" should print "ab:"

this is the code i wrote, it converts the last two to decimal but its unable to convert that decimal to ASCII characters. i tried to use .toString() to accomplish it, but no success.

```
 private static String unmangle(String word)
 {      
    String newTemp = word.substring(word.indexOf('%')+1);
    int hex = hexToInt(newTemp);
    String strI = Integer.toString(hex);

    System.out.println(strI);

    word=word.replace("%", "");
    word=word.replace("+", " ");
    return word = word.replace(newTemp, "")+ strI;


}
```

Comment: It sounds like you actually want http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: You probably should say ".. the last two characters ..", or perhaps ".. the last two digits ..", instead of using the word "decimal" above.  In fact, as your code states, you're converting from "hex" (short for "hexadecimal") to integer.  (But you then mess up by converting to decimal.)

Comment: Why are you reinventing `java.net.URLDecoder?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close: all you need is a cast instead of a call of `Integer.toString` -

```
private static String unmangle(String word)
{      
    String newTemp = word.substring(word.indexOf('%')+1);
    char hex = (char)hexToInt(newTemp);

    word=word.replace("%", "");
    word=word.replace("+", " ");
    return word = word.replace(newTemp, "")+ hex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should know how to make Hex to ASCII.

```
String newTemp=word.substring(word.length-1,word.length);
char a=newTemp.substring(0,0);
char b=newTemp.substring(1,1);
int c=0,d=0;
//And you should convert to int.
if(a='A'|'a')
c=10;//the same to d.
//and 
c=c*16+d;
String strI = Integer.toString(c);
return word.substring(0,word.length-2)+strI;
```

I am so sorry my English is not well. And this is my way to deal with this question.String `strI = Integer.toString(hex);`

this sentence is wrong.It makes hex to string.For example if hex=97,StrI="97" not "a"